# error when uploading images when creating the product in cloudinary nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudinary

I am experiencing an error that when I create a product and add some images to it, I get an error:

```
"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')",
"stack": "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

I tried it both in the frontend and in postman and I got an error, I don't really understand the error because it is. I really don't know if I'm misapplying the logic or if I'm missing something, if it's clear to me that it's because of the logic of the cloudinary upload because when I delete that code fragment the product is created normally but without image

code

```
// Creando productos
export const newProduct = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
    // agregar imagenes
    let images = [];
    if (typeof req.body.images === 'string') {
        images.push(req.body.images);
    } else {
        images = req.body.images;
    }

    let imagesLinks = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        const result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(images[i], {
            folder: 'products',
        });

        imagesLinks.push({
            public_id: result.public_id,
            url: result.secure_url,
        });
    }

    req.body.images = imagesLinks;
    req.body.user = req.user.id
    const product = await productsModel.create(req.body.images, req.body.user);
    res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        data: product,
    });
});
```

Comment: images is undefined have you tried logging `req.body.images`

Comment: no, how should I do it ?

Comment: I found the error, if it was ````req.body.images``` in the frontend it was called as images.